# Can Rmarkdown having a non working code, knit html output showing the errors and warnings

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown

Lets say I have code in R which is `not working`, i.e. I run that code and get some errors and warnings, and I want to share the code and output showing errors and warnings, with the third person through `R markdown`.

**Is it possible to knit R markdown if I have errors in r code chunks?, If yes, then is it going to show me waht errors and warnings occurs in the html output?** Goal is to share the `html output` showing errors and everything with the non working code.

Any help on this is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: you might want to use `try` or `trycatch` so you can deal with the errors as you want

Comment: @RichardTelford I have never used one of these error handling methods in R. I am familiar with error handling in java although. Will check on R how it works. Thanks for reminding me of these. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, use `knitr::opts_chunk$set(error = TRUE)`

Here is the full markdown:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
date: "September 21, 2016"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, error = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown

Here is my error

```{r}
1 + 1
1 + "a"
```
````

Output:

[image: Error]

Comment: That looks great. Just to confirm, I have a kind of a complex code and separate experiments n stuff which I run inside different r chunks. So, it knitting the rmd wont truncate truncate right because each chunk has some errors.

Comment: Its working. Thanks a ton Chris..!!! Worth asking, jsut realized I didnt read the default markdown, which just had that setup with you adding that `error =TRUE`. Thanks. Will check for warnings also.

Comment: @SowmyaS.Manian you can set the options for each chunk individually with ```{r, error = TRUE} , or globally as I have done above

Comment: @Chris..Thank you, I was able to knit pdf succesfully without any problem. This way its useful to share non working or trouble shooting parts of code.  I knew the individual chunk settings, but usually the whole code sometimes ends up truncating the knitting part. Anyways. Thanks again!

Comment: Is it possible to hide error messages at all from the output?